# How to fail a Cypress test if text wraps at wrong point

Tags: testing, next.js, cypress

So I am trying to write a test that checks multiple viewports if an element wraps at certain words. I am using Next.JS with component testing. Here is an example:

The test should pass if it wraps like this:

[image: Test should pass]

If it wraps like this it should fail:

[image: Test should fail]

Here is the structure of the text:

```
<h1 class="text-[5rem] w-full leading-none text-left">
<span class=" inline-block font-extrabold">H</span>
<span class=" inline-block font-extrabold">e</span>
<span class=" inline-block font-extrabold">l</span>
<span class=" inline-block font-extrabold">l</span>
<span class=" inline-block font-extrabold">o</span>
<span class=" inline-block font-extrabold">,</span>
<br>
</h1>
```

Comment: Hi Adam, can you please add more additional informations?
How does the expected HTML Code look like?

Comment: @DieGraueEminenz I have updated the post with the relevant information

Comment: You may want to explore visual testing tool for checking the wrapped text.

Comment: @jjhelguero which tool would you suggest

Comment: There are several plugins for visual testing. I personal have not experimented with any of them, but have read about applitools.
https://docs.cypress.io/plugins/directory#Visual%20Testing

Comment: What is "wrong point"? The question lacks a clear requirement definition.

Comment: @TesterDick I updated the description to remove some ambiguity. I want it to only wrap at certain words

Answer (score 2):

You don't give a very precise requirement, just a couple of images. I'm going to assume you don't want to break mid-word, as that looks most likely.

```js
cy.get('h1 span')
  .should($spans => {

    const result = offsets.reduce((acc,current) => {
      if (acc.lastOffset && current[0].offsetTop > lastOffset) {
        acc.breaks.push(current.text())
      }
      acc.lastOffset= current[0].offsetTop
      return acc
    }, {breaks:[], lastOffset:null})

    // only breaks on spaces
    expect(result.breaks.every(breakChar => breakChar === ' ').to.eq(true)
  })
```

Comment: I want it to only break at certain words

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach it is to measure the height of the element, [HTMLElement.offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight).

For example

```js
cy.viewport(...)  // ensure viewport size is known

...

cy.get('h1')
  .should($h1 => {
    const height = $h1[0].offsetHeight
    expect(height).to.be.lt(300)
  })
```

Comment: That is true. Is it possible to get the height of a character in the font size?

Comment: It probably is, but your test will be much more straight-forward if you measure the height in a "correct" state and code the expected height explicitly.

Comment: It's like a manual version of visual testing but less setup and maintenance.

Comment: What do you mean by "correct" state